# How many processes are created after four fork() in Linux?

Tags: c, linux, operating-system

I have a dumb question seeing on the Operating system textbook. The question is below:
**Assume that all fork system calls are successful.After executing program shown below. How many lines are on the screen?**
I assume that every fork call doubles the processes, so the result should be 16 process are created. But when I type the same code from the textbook, I got 30 lines. Here is the result and the code:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/q9jgf.jpg

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(){
    fork();
    printf("After fork1\n");
    fork();
    printf("After fork2\n");
    fork();
    printf("After fork3\n");
    fork();
    printf("After fork4\n");
}
```

Comment: Forking forks the forks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the result should be like this:

`fork1
    fork2
        fork3
            fork4
            fork4
        fork3
            fork4
            fork4

    fork2
        fork3
            fork4
            fork4
        fork3
            fork4
            fork4
fork1
    fork2
        fork3
            fork4
            fork4
        fork3
            fork4
            fork4

    fork2
        fork3
            fork4
            fork4
        fork3
            fork4
            fork4`

(the spaces are only for better reading)

Comment: This answer could be improved with a number

Answer (score 5):

> But when I type the same code from the textbook, I got 30 lines

It's normal:

- After fork 1, you have 2 process, so 2 lines are written,
- After fork 2, you have 4 process, so 4 lines are written,
- After fork 3, you have 8 process, so 8 lines are written,
- After fork 4, you have 16 process, so 16 lines are written,

2+4+8+16 equals 30: you have 30 lines.